# hide index.html in the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I just saw the site [The Geek Designer](http://thegeekdesigner.com/) and love his URL. 
when you click on a navigation point, e.g. about, the URL display `/about/`. Without `index.html` at the end. 
so i tried it for myself: 
i create the directory about with only one index.html file inside. and create the hyperlink: 
`<a href="http://www.abc.com/about/>` 
but the URL display `/about/index.html` ! 
So how can i hide the index.html? **i do not use PHP and can't edit the .htaccess file!**

Comment: Are you using any web server? What is the web server are you using?

Comment: Check your web server configuration !

Comment: Are you a back-end framework for this?

Comment: @RussellGutierrez: What is this? *Big Smile*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try an URL Rewriting in your .htaccess file ?

Comment: can't edit the .htaccess from the server... and i never had edit files like this before.

Comment: This isn't an answer...how did it get accepted? The next answer is actually the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Apache this might help you 
[mod_rewrite: A Beginner's Guide to URL Rewriting Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)

If you htaccess file then add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: so i must either edit the .htaccess file or use PHP. nothing other?

Comment: i know mod_rewrite and htaccess they are many approaches with which you can change your url but htaccess is most of simple approach

Comment: ok. all of the 3 answers are the same content and correct. all 3 +1 but i accept the first who post it.
thanks for your help...

Answer (score -1):

You make folders on your servers and put your index there (with all the files needed). Ex: "www.example.com/prices", where "prices" for example, is a folder. It will not show index.html in adress bar.